# Amazon Fire TV css transitions

Tags: css, transition

Does anyone know how to trigger GPU acceleration for CSS transitions in web apps on the Amazon Fire TV box?  The demo Amazon provides manages to achieve it pretty well but I can't seem to mimic it at all.

All I'm trying to do is scroll a strip of images left and right through a container, I've tried adding -webkit-transform: translateX(0) on the div container and on the pictures container (in different combinations) but it still seems slow compared to the demo.  Also if you scroll too fast all the pictures disappear and reappear.  It's all a bit rubbish.  Does anyone know what might speed this up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem may be somewhere else in your code, the translateX(0) on its own doesn't provide a one size fits all solution.

Sometimes you can trigger hardware acceleration with something like:

```
.element {
   -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

on top of your current CSS.

However, I suggest you check the Web app starter Kit for Fire TV available at https://github.com/amzn/web-app-starter-kit-for-fire-tv/.

In the _common.scss file you can find the best practices on how to take full advantage of the hardware acceleration on device, especially around the Shoveler View:
https://github.com/amzn/web-app-starter-kit-for-fire-tv/blob/master/src/common/scss/_common.scss#L274